# how to apply overflow:hidden for children of children with absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been stumped on this question for quite some time and can't seem to find an answer. I have a parent div with a child that also has children. Below is a screenshot with added borders. The Parent is in red, the child in blue, and the children of the child in yellow. I want the red box to clip the yellow boxes. However, **overflow:hidden** only applies to the first generation of children and therefore does not affect the yellow boxes.

[image: diagram]

here is the desired result
[image: desired result]

The project is also running on a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/travisc671/pen/YzvObbX?editors=1010)

```
HTML
<div class='red'>
  <div class='blue'>
    <div class='yellow' />
    <div class='yellow' />
  </div>
</div>

CSS
.red {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.blue {
  position: absolute;
}
.yellow{
  position: absolute;
}
```

I need this to work for absolute positioning, as this project is supposed to be the ground for visual scripting. All feedback is welcome!

Comment: can you draw out the result you want.

Comment: Can you please share full HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: position: relative to the grandparent

Comment: @TemaniAfif TYSM! That worked